# Has a concept of good been defined separate from an anthropogenic perspective?

Tags: good-and-evil, objectivity

I am looking for a concept or word which may have been contrived that frames the attribute of “goodness” outside of any anthropogenic consideration. It would form the basis for measuring if an event “mattered” or not, completely independent of consequences to or for humans or humanity.

Has any concept been contrived to contain this concept without an anthropogenic standard?

This is a noumenal question, not an existential question.

Comment: Religions define gods which exist and attribute value to events independent of humanity. But it would seem that agency is always required to define good and bad.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that *"goodness"* would most generally mean *"fit for a purpose"*, whether that's a human/anthropogenic purpose or not. But whether or not the whole concept of *"purpose"* can itself exist independently of human perception is a bit vague, at least to me. Cats, dogs, and even plants, etc, can have their own *"purposes"*, but maybe (or maybe not) perceiving that notion requires humans. If not, then https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/us/fit-for-purpose provides various one-word synonyms (one of which is *"good"*).